# Capybara: Select or click a link in a dropdown list

Tags: list, menu, click, capybara

I have been looking for the answer but could't find any answer. Maybe I am missing to understand some fundamental concept of capybara.

I have a dropdown-menu, by use of "ul"

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
  <li id="dropdown-list"> 
    <span>myList</span> 
    <ul> 
      <li><%= link_to 'Link1', controller: 'link_1' %> </li> 
      <li><%= link_to 'Link2', controller: 'link_2' %> </li> 
    </ul> 
  </li>
  <li id="a_different_dropdown"> 
    <span>A different dropdown list</span>     
  </li> 
</ul>
```

I want to click on Link2. The only thing I've been able to do is:

```
find('.dropdown-menu', :text => 'myList')
```

Conceptually: when I have a dropdown menu, do I have to split the process in many steps? I mean, do I have to click in the option `myList` to make sub-options visible?

I tried click, click_link and select methods but I was unable to open Link2 as the error was often:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:Unable to find link Link2
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably have to click the dropdown list first.  Items in the dropdown menu are usually not visible.

```
find('#dropdown-list').click
```

Then you could inspect the options in the list and see what's there.

I'm not really sure what your HTML source looks like, but a lot of the time selecting an option from a dropdown can be done in one line:

```
find('#dropdown-list option', :text => 'foo').click
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the similar issue & you can fix it by this line.

```
find(:css, '.dropdown-menu').click_on(".a_different_dropdown")
```

**Update 1**

As per official document

```
select('Option', :from => 'Select Box')
```

---

For reference: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Answer (score 2):

See if this works

```
find(:xpath, '//option[contains(text(), "Link2")]').select_option
```

No need to make the option visible to select it, sometimes Capybara's default DSL has not worked for me in the past.

Comment: Failure/Error: find(:xpath, '//option[contains(text(), "Maintenance Jobs")]').select_option
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "//option[contains(text(), \"Maintenance Jobs\")]"

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML select dropdown source code? This should ideally work if the option is present.